# Old 2004 FreeBSD Box & SSH

Tags: startup, bios

Been years since putting backups on it. Now, need to get them off. Trying `ssh` & `scp`. The dreaded "no matching cipher" message. Yes, I would update it, if I could, but would rather not.

So. My idea is? Use a USB bootable stick, with (newest) FreeBSD on it. For i386 Athlon architecture. The BIOS shows these for options. Which **USB xxx** do I choose?

- USB FDD
- USB CDROM
- USB HDD
- USB RMD-FDD
- USB ZIP/MO

Outside of setup a plain FTP box on VPN. Would be only other alternative. Unless someone has a suggestion on that too?

Comment: As it's a thumb drive, it *should* be `USB HDD` as it's effectively a hard disk drive.

Comment: Does this works ? `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 <YOUR SSH HOSTNAME>`

Comment: Get this error: `Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.122 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` not supported either? But no problem.

Comment: And: `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 <YOUR SSH HOSTNAME>` ?

Comment: @Gilles Quenot Fantastic! group1-ssh1 __worked__ Thank you, very much. Considered answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers that were manufactured after USB flash drives became ubiquitous are logical about identifying USB flash drives in the UEFI/BIOS boot sequence, but this is often not the case with very old computers.

USB FDD stands for USB floppy disk drive, which didn't seem right to me, but it successfully booted a USB stick on an old computer when the other BIOS boot options didn't. USB HDD stands for USB hard disk drive which seems logical to me like it should work if the USB stick doesn't boot when the USB FDD option is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 <HOST>
```